# Windows Server Appfabric caching and high availability

Tags: windows-server-2008, high-availability, appfabric

We are in the process of converting a solution to use Windows Server Appfabric Caching.

We are wondering:

- How do you turn on the high availability option? Such that the cache is stored on more than one server.
- Is the High availability option only available when running Windows Server Enterprise Edition?
- If one machine goes down how long will it take before the others take over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn on high availability for a cache, you set the `Secondaries` option when you use the 'new-cache' Powershell comandlet e.g.

```
new-cache MyCache -Secondaries 1
```

See the [New-Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428191%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) documentation on MSDN.

Yes, high availability only works on Server 208 Enterprise Edition.